# OpenGL drawing on DirectX Form

Tags: c#, c++

I have a **dll** that draws a triangle in **OpenGL Form** through a method `"GlutCreateWindow("Name of the Window")"`.

I am using that **dll** in my **Direct X application**.

I want that the drawing must be done on my **Direct X** Form not on **OpenGL Form**...

I am sending my **Direct X** form handle as a parameter to the the method but the application exited when it reaches the `"GlutCreateWindow("Name of the Window")"` line.

I have tried several different **Glut Windows Management Method** like `GlutCreateSubWindow()`, `GlutSetWindow()` etc but nothing brings my desired result...

is this a doable task that i am working for?

Please help...

Comment: interesting, but why?

Comment: DirectX and OpenGL are not compatible. So if you create handle using DX, you can not use it for OpenGL. I think, once handle is paired with either of devices, its locked for it.

Comment: I have an exe project in c++. i want to use it in C# application as a dll. i have created its dll and called it in my C# application.

Now the application firing exception of "Interprocess Communication"...how can i get rid of this?

is it a do-able task that i have converted an exe to dll and using it in c# application. is it possible?

any help will appreciate obviously...

Comment: Yes making a dll of an exe application and calling it in the code is a do-able stuff...i have done it...